# How to save a List<ParseUser> from String[] of object ids

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this, but I can't find an answer in the [Parse docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide). I'm trying to save a `List<ParseUser>` from `String[]` of object ids of the users. Is there a simple way of doing this?

My subclass of `ParseObject`'s mutator method has a method signature of type `List<ParseUser>`.

i.e. `public void setX(List<ParseUser> value) {...}`

Would it be possible to change the method signature to a String[] of the individual object ids?

Do I have to query for all the users from the object ids and then save them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to query the Parse API (via the SDK). You will provide it with a list of ID's and then the API will return a `List<ParseUser>`

There is an example [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#users-querying).